# Inner join con duplicados SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo las siguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla de inscripciones]

Cuando realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
select   cia.fecha_inscripcion, ccaa.id_cuota, rc.descripcion, cde.id_documento, cdr.descripcion_documentacion

 from cole_inscripcion_alumnos cia  
 left join cole_cuotas_asignadas_alumno ccaa on   cia.id_inscripcion = ccaa.id_inscripcion
right join registro_cuotas rc on rc.id_cuota = ccaa.id_cuota

left join cole_documentacion_entregada cde on cde.id_inscripcion = ccaa.id_inscripcion 
left join cole_documentacion_requerida cdr on cdr.id_docu = cde.id_documento

 where cia.id_inscripcion = 3
```

Me devuelve los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me devuelve datos duplicados,  alguna idea de como resolver este problema?

Pero yo quisiera recibir algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido ZORMAT a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Sin ver los datos es imposible  responder tu pregunta, te sugiero que construyas un [mcve]

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho  ya he arreglado la pregunta

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que te duplica los datos, te refieres a que descripción te aparece varias veces o a que campo exactamente?

Comment: La descripcion y el id_cuota se repite varias veces

Answer (score 0):

ZORMAT.

Prueba con este query. Al no tener mucha información sobre la relación de las tablas y lo que contiene cada una, hace un poco laboriosa la tarea de verificación, pero espero que sea de ayuda. Por cierto, si requieres alguna función lógica para determinar el id_documento, deberías mencionarlo para considerarlo en el query.

```
SELECT
q1.*
, dr.descripcion_documentacion
FROM
(
    SELECT
    cia.fecha_inscripcion
    , ccaa.id_cuota
    , rc.descripcion
    , CASE WHEN (ccaa.id_cuota = 3)
        THEN 11
        ELSE CASE WHEN (ccaa.id_cuota = 5)
        THEN 7
            ELSE CASE WHEN (ccaa.id_cuota = 6)
            THEN 9
            ELSE 10
            END
        END
    END id_docu
    FROM cole_inscripcion_alumnos cia  
    LEFT JOIN cole_cuotas_asignadas_alumno ccaa
    ON cia.id_inscripcion = ccaa.id_inscripcion
    LEFT JOIN registro_cuotas rc 
    ON rc.id_cuota = ccaa.id_cuota
    GROUP BY
    cia.fecha_inscripcion
    , ccaa.id_cuota
    , rc.descripcion
) q1
LEFT JOIN cole_documentacion_requerida dr
ON q1.id_docu = dr.id_docu
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alma,pero aún me duplica los campos

Comment: ¿Me muestras el output? Para saber cuál es el problema.

Comment: Saludos Alma, aquí puedes ver el resultado

https://zormat.dev/resultado.JPG

Comment: Modifiqué el query, por favor verifica si te es útil y cualquier duda, coméntala.